# Make a selection wider

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, transform

I have an object that is a rectangle which has a 20px wide border. I want to resize the rectangle, but to maintain its border width. If I select it and use Transform I will have a smaller border width after the transformation. So I want to make it first wider. How to do it? Is there some other way?

The rectangle looks similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Select and delete/mask the middle and move the top of the frame down?

Comment: IS this a vector layer... Since if it is then there is a better option than what you use. If its not why the hell not.

Comment: I use that image just as an example. My rectangle is not exactly like this, but very similar. You mean to use Adobe Illustrator instead of Photoshop? It's another solution too. Maybe the best, but I don't have enough experience in Illustrator and Im trying to find the best in Photoshop.

Comment: Is this in photoshop? If you have the chance to use illustrator just for this resizing you want to do i might be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the border is a stroke than after resizing you can reapply the stroke value.

If the image is a vector path you can use Object>Transform>Scale and do not check the box "Scale stroke and effects", the border will stay the same width.

Or, if it is a vector path, you can take the white arrow tool and select all the points on the left half and slide them to the right, making the frame narrower and keeping border the same thickness.

If the frame is a fixed rastered image file like .jpg than you should copy half the frame, paste it in place, slide it away to make the frame bigger:

https://youtu.be/vlJHXnJ9WOw

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions:
1. using Edit -> Content Aware Scale

2. transform (I did it smaller) the inner part of border's selection and fill in with borders colour.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with illustrator, I guess the best way to do that is to re-create the image and have a "Stroke" with "Inside" settings that way even if you resize the image the border will keep the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut (command/control X) 1/2 of the image and paste in the same spot (will go on a new layer). Make sure the background is transparent.
2. Then you can move the two layers closer to each other to make narrower.
3. Merge back together into one layer.